# How to print a sequence stacked in a "pyramid" with alternating sort?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, range, sequence

I want to print the following sequence of integers in a pyramid (odd rows sorted ascending, even rows sorted descending). If `S=4`, it must print four rows and so on.

Expected output:

```
1
3 2
4 5 6
10 9 8 7
```

I tried out the following code but it produced the wrong output.

```
S=int(input())
for i in range(1,S+1):
    y=i+(i-1)
    if i%2!=0:
        print(*range(i,y+1))
    elif i%2==0:
        print(*range(y,i-1,-1))

# Output:
# 1
# 3 2
# 3 4 5
# 7 6 5 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some way of either keeping track of where you are in the sequence when printing each row, generating the entire sequence and then chunking it into rows, or... (the list of possible approaches goes on and on).

Below is a fairly simple approach that just keeps track of a range start value, calculates the range stop value based on the row number, and reverses even rows.

```
rows = int(input())
start = 1
for n in range(1, rows + 1):
    stop = int((n * (n + 1)) / 2) + 1
    row = range(start, stop) if n % 2 else reversed(range(start, stop))
    start = stop
    print(*row)

# If rows input is 4, then output:
# 1
# 3 2
# 4 5 6
# 10 9 8 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.count` and just reversing the sublist before printing on even rows

from itertools import count

```
s = 4
l = count(1)
for i in range(1, s+1):
    temp = []
    for j in range(i):
        temp.append(next(l))
    if i % 2:
        print(' '.join(map(str, temp)))
    else:
        print(' '.join(map(str, temp[::-1])))
```

> ```
> 1
> 3 2
> 4 5 6
> 10 9 8 7
> ```